# Why Apache IoTDB Version 0.12.4 did not return data unless adding `order by time desc`?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I use Version 0.12.4 of Apache IoTDB, and would like to ask what caused this situation? When I execute `select * from root.kantian.data.SKY_C3.442C05954CE7` command, data cannot be found and returned `null`. But data can be found by adding the reverse order condition, for example, `select * from root.kantian.data.SKY_C3.442C05954CE7 order by time desc limit 10`. Why did this situation happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that has already been solved in Version 0.13.4 of Apache IoTDB. Therefore, it is recommended to upgrade your IoTDB to this version.